# SQL Server Deadlock Primary Key Same Table S vs U Lock

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-deadlocks

Can someone please help me with this deadlock? So far, I am stumped.

As far as I can tell, the records are being updated in the same order in both procs, so I don't understand what is causing this deadlock.

Any ideas?

```
deadlock-list
deadlock victim=process225a3ac108
 process-list
....
resource-list
  keylock hobtid=72057603958046720 dbid=12 objectname=RV.dbo.RP_Accounts indexname=PK_RP_Accounts id=lock64e394980 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057603958046720
   owner-list
    owner id=processb6357d088 mode=X
   waiter-list
    waiter id=process225a3ac108 mode=S requestType=wait
  keylock hobtid=72057603958046720 dbid=12 objectname=RV.dbo.RP_Accounts indexname=PK_RP_Accounts id=lock1a4720f980 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057603958046720
   owner-list
    owner id=process225a3ac108 mode=X
   waiter-list
    waiter id=processb6357d088 mode=U requestType=wait
```

Both processes are deadlocking on the same update statement, which has the form:

```
update RP_Accounts
set AccountName = @Name, ...
where AccountId = @Id
```

AccountId is the primary key and clustered index.

Comment: It might be worth exploring what locks are taken by one such update with an extended events session. If it's the PK though, you should only ever be updating one row with that. Hmm…

Comment: Is the code in a transaction? What happens before the update statement?

Comment: Waht statement is executed before ? Do you have a select statement ?

Comment: Yes, it's in a transaction. There are no select statements before the update. I'm starting to wonder if the records are somehow being submitted in different orders from different processes. It happens via our public API, and only when it gets hammered. I guess I need to setup better logging to see what's going on.